# AlloyUI: Add Element on object 'modal'

Tags: alloy-ui

I try to create a Portlet which use a JSP with Alloy UI to display informations.

I like the effect of the module 'Modal' - [Link](http://alloyui.com/examples/modal/real-world/)

The effect is, that a box opens, if I click a button (you can see it if you follow the link).

There are two buttons in this example. I want to replace them by a text field / input field.

How can I do this?

Sincerely, JC.

Comment: The `bodyContent` property will render any html within it. Older versions of the framework allowed for [content loading](http://alloyui.com/versions/1.5.x/examples/dialog/real-world/), however, the dialog approach appears to be deprecated. I'd assume the basic concept is still achievable with the latest [I/O](http://alloyui.com/examples/io/real-world/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, 'contentBox' worked fine.
I added to the modal object

```
contentBox: '#contentBox',
```

and defined a div container with my textbox in

```
<div id="contentBox">
    <aui:form>
        <aui:fieldset>
            <aui:input name="productName" size="45" />
            <aui:button-row>
                <aui:button id="closeModal" value="Close" class="btn"></aui:button>
                <aui:button type="submit" onSubmit="cm();" />
            </aui:button-row>
        </aui:fieldset>
    </aui:form>
</div>
```

I don't know if there is a better solution, but I had to write the div container in the html content, but I wanted to display it only in the modal box that opens by click. So I had to hide it, it works by adding

```
render: '#modal',
```

to the modal object.